# Use switchMap with Kedno UI Gid in Angular2+

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, kendo-ui-angular2, switchmap

I use Kendo UI for Angular Grid with data binding. I have two services: one to emit   search event from filter component to grid component and one (based on BehaviorSubject) to call API.

The way of data binding with Grid that I use is based on Kendo examples. The problem is how to use switchMap to cancel API requests when user is typing text in filter input. I know the switchMap operator but i don't know how to use it in Kendo UI Grid based Service. I have tried many ways without success and i have no more ideas. My code below:

**API Service methods used in Grid component**

```
public query(state: any): void {  
    this.getItems(state)
        .subscribe(x =>   
            super.next(x));  
}  

private getItems(state: any): Observable<GridDataResult>{  
    let page = state.skip / state.take + 1;
    let queryStr =         
    `page=` + page + 
    `&size=` + state.take + 
    `&sortColumn=` + state.sortColumn + 
    `&sortDirection=` + state.sortDirection;

    return this.http  
        .get(`${this.BASE_URL}FindItemsComplex?${queryStr}`)  
        .pipe(
            map(response => (<GridDataResult>{
                data: response['data'],
                total: response['length']
            }))
        );  
}
```

**Grid Component methods**

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.subscription = this.searchService.searchEvent.
   debounceTime(400).
   subscribe((searchModel: ItemsFilter) => 
     {
       this.state = searchModel;   
       this.state.skip = 0;   
       this.state.take = 15;
       this.service.query(this.state);  
     }
   );    
 }
```

Where and how i should use switchMap?
Thank you for your help.

EDIT

**Filter component method used for emitting event**

HTML

```
<input kendoTextBox [(ngModel)]="itemsFilter.textSearch" (ngModelChange)="onSearch()" [ngClass]="'form-control'" />
```

TS

```
onSearch() {
   this.searchService.Search(this.itemsFilter);
}
```

**Search service**

```
export class ItemsSearchService {
   constructor() {
       this.searchEvent = new EventEmitter();
   }

   Search(query :ItemsFilter) {
       this.searchEvent.emit(query);
   }

   searchEvent: EventEmitter<ItemsFilter>;
}
```

Comment: can you include the function that is called when a user enters text into the filte rcomponent?

Answer (score 0):

Function 'debounceTime' can also cancel API requests when user is typing text in filter input like 'switchMap'. You already use 'debounceTime', So you don't need use 'switchMap' again.

Comment: My experience is different, I'd like to kill all previous requests and let the last to be invoked. But now with 'debounceTime' I have cases when I got response from API from request which was invoked a moment earlier and last request most likely has finished faster. So current state of input filter and data in table doesn't match

Comment: debounceTime will kill all previous requests and just let the last to be invoked as you like.
see the below statement from the office site:https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/debounceTime
debounceTime delays values emitted by the source Observable, but drops previous pending delayed emissions if a new value arrives on the source Observable.

Comment: check the example may you can find an answer.
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/inputs/debounce-valuechange/